Prevents Windows Terminal as Default Terminal Apps Temporarily
I'm running Windows 11 with WT installed and as default terminal app. All scripts will opened in WT.
For some reason, I want to run a ps1 file (from its file >Right-Click> Open with PowerShell) without going through windows terminal.
Therefore, maybe I have to change the wt settings when running the file, then return it to the original settings when finished.
Basically, I just need to change the following settings via script:

change it from windows terminal to windows console host, then return it to default when done.
How do I do it programmatically?
I looked for that setting in the setting.json file of wt, so I can change it, but I didn't find it.

how do you start your script? Do you start it from WT and then expect to get a powershell windows?
you can try using conhost if you start the script from wt: conhost.exe powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "script.ps1"

that would (well in my case) still open windows terminal. @Mr.Key7. Maybe I'm getting the question wrong :)
